# FunSet Elm- fold operation

Tags: elm, fold

I am trying to solve this question.

```
type alias FunSet = Int -> Bool          
contains : FunSet -> Int -> Bool   
contains set elem = set elem

singletonSet : Int -> FunSet  
singletonSet elem = \inputElem -> elem == inputElem

union : FunSet -> FunSet -> FunSet   
union a b = (\x -> (contains a x) || (contains b x))
```

My fold function should do the following:
Takes a list of sets and returns a new set, which is build by applying a fold using `operation` function.

```
fold: List FunSet -> ( FunSet -> FunSet -> FunSet ) -> FunSet
fold operation sets =
```

Example:

```
(fold union [(singletonSet 1), (singletonSet 2), (singletonSet 3)]) 1 == True
```

It is not clear to me how should I do this. Hope someone can help ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `List.foldl` or `List.foldr` for this:

```
fold sets f = 
  case sets of
    [] -> \_ -> False
    x :: xs -> List.foldl f x xs
```

I feel it would be easier to define `emptySet _ = False` and directly use `List.foldl`:

```
List.foldl union emptySet [(singletonSet 1), (singletonSet 2), (singletonSet 3)]
```

Note that the first parameter of `List.foldl` is a function that takes first an element and then the accumulator, rather than the other way around, so you can't simply use `fold sets diff`, you'd have to use `fold sets (flip diff)` to flip the arguments.

Comment: Good. I made it work for union. Buut now I have another problem, I am trying to do the same thing for difference too.  For this example: (fold diff [setOf [1, 2, 3], setOf [1], setOf [2]] ) 3 == True

Comment: @Myii What problem did you run into?

Comment: for that example, it should return True, but it returns False. I don't really understand the concept of using fold for difference either. I have a separate function diff: diff : FunSet -> FunSet -> FunSet
diff a b = (\x -> contains a x && (not (contains b x))). How should I apply fold on this?

Comment: @Myii It's because of the order of the arguments. Try `(\b a -> diff a b)` instead